# SDL2 cannot open any BMP files

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Im trying to play around with SDL2 following lazyfoo's tutorials to get accustomed to it, but even the basic most program doesn't work properly. I can open a basic blank window with no image and keep it open, but as soon as I try to open a BMP file in a window, it all acts weird and doesn't work anymore. My code, that initially shows no errors:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <cstdio>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

SDL_Window *newWindow = nullptr;
SDL_Surface *loadedImage = nullptr;
SDL_Surface *screenSurface = nullptr;
bool quit = false;
SDL_Event event;

bool initWindow() {
    bool state = true;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::puts("Error init");
        state = false;
    }
    else
    {
        newWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                     SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                     SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN);

        if (nullptr == newWindow)
        {
            std::puts("Error window");
            state = false;
        }
        else
        {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(newWindow);
        }
    }
    return state;
}

bool loadMedia() {
    bool success = true;

    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP("LAND3.BMP");

    if (loadedImage == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Error image %s \n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void closeWindow() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    loadedImage = nullptr;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(newWindow);
    newWindow = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {

    if (!initWindow())
    {
        std::puts("Error init main");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!loadMedia())
        {
            std::puts("Error image main");
        }
        else
        {
            while (!quit)
            {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    SDL_BlitSurface(loadedImage, nullptr, screenSurface, nullptr);
                    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(newWindow);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closeWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

When running this program, I get no errors but the UI starts acting all crazy; resolution gets very small(way smaller than 480p set up by me), all windows resize and this lasts for a brief period. If I replace the `while(!quit)` loop with a `SDL_Delay(1000)`, this behaviour lasts approximately as long as the delay.

Initially my suspicion was that the file I was using the first time was corrupted(I had just renamed an existing picture), but then I downloaded a sample BMP file and nothing changed.

When using the debugger I get an error from `loadMedia()` that the file could not be loaded, regardless of which one I use. I am using MinGW and cLion.

What might be the issue?

Comment: "When using the debugger I get an error from `loadMedia()` that the file could not be loaded" -- That function will print out an SDL error string, if it fails. What exactly is being printed out?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the text of  `SDL_GetError()` is "Couldn't open LAND3.BMP". Regardless of what file I input, the error is the same, apart from the photo name.

Comment: You must either put the file in the [current working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) of your program or you must specify the absolute path to the file, for example `"C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Desktop\\LAND3.BMP"`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel weirdly enough it usually works when i just use the name of the file, as it was in the same folder as main. Anyways, it still fucked up my interface, only this time it didnt even stop. Neither did task manager help, i literally had to forcefully shut down windows only for it to start updating when booting back up. [Windows was looking like this](https://ibb.co/pz39DLv) . I guess this is when me and SDL part ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` is not a valid flag for the function `SDL_CreateWindow`. That constant is not intended as a flag, but as an [event ID](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID). You probably meant to use the constant `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` instead.

The constant `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN` happens to have the same value as `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` (both have the value `1`). Therefore, your incorrect function call

```
newWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                     SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                     SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN);
```

is equivalent to:

```
newWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                     SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                     SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
```

In other words, you are unintentionally asking SDL to create the window in 640*480 **fullscreen** mode. That is probably the reason for your desktop being resized.

The reason for the file not being found is probably because the file is not in your program's [current working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory). You can either ensure that the file is in that directory or you can use an absolute path to the file, for example `"C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Desktop\\LAND3.BMP"`.

I doubt that your problem of not being able to kill your application using the task manager is the fault of SDL. It is probably a design flaw of Microsoft Windows. See [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170425-00/?p=96035) on how to make the task manager more accessible from a hung fullscreen application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate taking your time to write a more detailed answer.

Comment: @AndreiVicol: I hope I have now persuaded you not to give up on SDL so quickly. :-) However, in case you are looking for alternatives, you may want to look at [SFML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_and_Fast_Multimedia_Library). Although I have never used it, from what I have read, the main difference seems to be that SFML provides an object-oriented C++ interface, whereas SDL only provides a C interface. Since you have tagged your question as C++ and not C, I thought that this was worth mentioning. However, SFML has a smaller user-base than SDL.